# How do I replace substring in a file name?

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I'm attempting to replace the substring "Dog_1" with "Dog_2" for every file in my directory using sed.

The file names look like this: Dog_1_interictal_segment_0472.csv

Here is the command I'm using:

`sed -i '' s/Dog_1/Dog_2/g *.csv`

For some reason the substring isn't being replaced.

Comment: The `''` should actually be embracing the expression. As in `sed -i 's/Dog_1/Dog_2/g' *.csv`.

Comment: Are your substitution strings _literally_ `Dog_1` and `Dog_2`, or are they something else that requires shell escaping, etc.?

Comment: @Rubens although I agree that sed scripts should be quoted, that one doesn't actually need it. The reason for those empty quotes is that `-i` takes a non-optional suffix on OS X, so `-i ''` edits in-place with no backup file.

Comment: @bux Didn't know `-i` had an optional argument on OS X. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, you're trying to *rename* the files? You can't use `sed` for that; that changes the *contents* of the files, without renaming them. Here's how I might do the renaming:

```
for a in Dog_1*.csv; do
  mv "$a" "Dog_2${a#Dog_1}"
done
```

Comment: nice, just miss files that have twice Dog_1 in the name (normaly not a lot hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

Since the question regards renaming of files, you may be better off `rename`ing them.
This application has syntax quite similar to `sed`'s:

```
rename 's/Dog_1/Dog_2/' *.csv
```

And you may as well perform *global* renamings, if that is the case:

```
rename 's/Dog_1/Dog_2/g' *.csv
```

Comment: Good utility, but question is tagged [tag:osx]. (See https://discussions.apple.com/message/8767758#8767758)

Comment: @bux Hmm, duly noted! Didn't know there *wasn't* a default rename in osx. Luckly the source is open :D